# Execute function on key down and key up in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a program that needs to execute a function when a key goes down and when said key is lifted. the function edits data in an array, and all the solutions that i've found keep executing the function while the key is pressed and not at all when it's lifted up. i would prefer it if it had no libraries (i dont know if thats the correct term)

Comment: Much more detail is needed.  To start with, in what context does this program execute?  Is it a local console app, a local GUI app, a web app, etc?

Comment: Its a web app. even a variable like keyDown would be fine.

Comment: Can you use the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` javascript event hooks?